# Set navigation property to null EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities `Inspection` and `User`

An `Inspection` has an `Approver` property which is a `User` hooked up like so `public virtual User Approver { get; set; }`

Sometimes `Approver` has to be set to `null`

I am doing it as follows

```
 Inspection rtrn = Context.Inspections.Where(x => x.Id == inspId).SingleOrDefault();
 rtrn.Approver = null;
 rtrn.ApprovalDate = new DateTime();

 base.Update(rtrn); //EF repo
```

The problem is that this does not set `Approver_Id` to `null` in the database. In fact if I put a break point at the `rtrn.ApprovalDate = new DateTime();` I can see that `rtrn.Approver` is still of type `User`. It looks as if it's ignoring the `rtrn.Approver = null;` line all together.

At the higher level I just want to break `Inspection` -- `User` association without deleting either entity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual property is just that, virtual. It is filled with the record that matches its corresponding foreign key, which is typically ApproverId (unless you specified a different ForeignKey with the ForeignKey attribute).

If you want to get rid of the Approver, then you just need to set the ApproverId to null.

Comment: Makes sense. The "problem" is I don't expose the foreign key. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without exposing it?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I suppose you could clear that value in the set of the virtual property whenever that gets a value of null assigned to it?

Comment: the foreign key way will actually be cleaner in my situation. Thank you